# 3G connection stalling after long periods of activity

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, usb, 3g

I have a Huawei E1752 3G dongle that is connected to a machine running the latest stable Debian. My problem is that after a long period of use (in the order of days), the 3G dongle seems to stall and no traffic goes through it, i.e., there is 100% packet loss. This applies to all network traffic.

What is strange is that this is not detected by pppd, pppd is alive and the blue light on the dongle is always on. My pppd config file specifies lcp-echo-interval and lcp-echo-failure, so these packets seem to go trough. In other words, the connection to my ISP seems to be active.

I have looked through the different relevant logfiles, tried different USB-ports (+hubs) and different Linux-distributions, without finding any relevant information or output. Therefore, I am wondering if anyone has experienced something similar or have any ideas on what to try?

My pppd configuration file looks like this:

```
460800
idle 7200
lock
crtscts
modem
noauth
linkname ppp1
#Netcom will always be ppp1
unit 1
# dns, routing
nodefaultroute
# avoid compression:
noccp
nobsdcomp
novj
user "internet"
password "internet"
# connect script
connect "/usr/sbin/hsdpa_chat.sh"
# t-mobile specific?
ipcp-restart 8
ipcp-max-configure 50
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote

#This tells pppd to send probes every N sec, and to fail after Y probes
lcp-echo-interval 2
lcp-echo-failure 3
```